# Query to determine percentage composition on a specific grouping of records

Tags: ms-access, view, group-by, aggregate

I want to analyse the Market capital of the Industry per Counterparty of the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| CPTY | Industry      | Value   |
--------------------------------------------------
| a    | food          | 10      |
| a    | water         | 5       |
| c    | wood          | 20      |
| c    | food          | 20      |
| d    | wood          | 10      |
```

I would like a breakdown of percentages for each of the CPTY fields in relation to their child Industries.

A sample of the output query I would expect should look like:

---

```
| CPTY | Industry      | Value   | %IndustryPerCpty
--------------------------------------------------
| a    | food          | 10      | 66.66
| a    | water         | 5       | 33.33
| c    | wood          | 20      | 50.0
| c    | food          | 20      | 50.0
| d    | wood          | 10      | 100.00
```

E.g. for CPTY *a*, the corresponding sectors are *food* and *water*. The total value for CPTY *a* is 10+5=15. Thus, *food* has 10/15*100% = 66.66% of the total market value for that CPTY. Likewise, *water* has 5/15 *100% = 33.33% of the total market value for that CPTY.

My original attempts at the query follow the structure adopted in [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692599/adding-a-percent-column-to-ms-access-query). However, this gives me percentage composition for each row, not the Industry per CPTY.

*Note: I don't expect the sum( %IndustryPerCpty ) column to equal 100%, for reasons I hope are clear.*

Can anyone suggest a query structure in Ms Access to generate my desired table with %IndustryPerCpty fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `[t]`, and that the `Value` column has been called `Val` (`Value` is a reserved word and complicates things), you can create a view (query) with the following SQL definition:

```
SELECT 
    t0.CPTY, t0.Industry, t0.Val * 100.0 / 
    (SELECT sum(t1.Val) FROM t AS t1    
      WHERE t1.CPTY = t0.CPTY) AS PerCentIndustryPerCpty
FROM 
    t AS t0;
```

You can make it using the "SQL view" instead of the graphical designer for views (querys).

You get this result:

[image: ViewPerCents]

---

If you don't feel comfortable with the SQL view, this can also be done within the GUI, in two steps:

1. Create a Query named `TotalsPerCPTY` with a column named `TotalValPerCPTY` that has the `SUM`s of `Val` `GROUPed BY` `CPTY`, as shown in the following image:

[image: TotalsPerCPTY Query]

2. Create the `ViePerCents` Query by joining the `t` table together with the `TotalsPerCPTY` view, using the `CPTY` column, with one computed column that computes `Val / TotalValPerCPTY * 100.0`:

[image: Final query]

Comment: Looks to be working great! Many thanks @joanolo